# OAuth2 callback launches activity inside the browser on some devices

Tags: android, oauth, oauth-2.0, redirect

I've implemented OAuth2 for Coinbase inside an Android app. The app flow is as follows. A user clicks on a "link with Coinbase" button, the call to the OAuth2 endpoint `https://www.coinbase.com/oauth/authorize` is made. Then the system browser opens up with the Coinbase OAuth page, where the user is asked to sign in and authorize the app. Once this is done, the app is called back via a custom URI scheme:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="myapp" android:pathPrefix="/coinbase-oauth" />
</intent-filter>
```

Inside the activity with this filter, **which is the same activity the user started the initial OAuth process from**, the `onNewIntent(Intent intent)` method is called getting the code via the intent and finishes the authorization by getting a token. This is the preferred way and how we want OAuth to behave, all good.

However, on some devices, the `BROWSABLE` activity is recreated inside the browser. We reach `onCreate()` of the activity and can also get the OAuth code from the intent, however, I am unable to get back into the app. The initial activity that launched the browser for authorization is still in the background waiting for a response. The newly created version of the activity is essentially decoupled. While it can finalize the job, I want users to get back into the app.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is nothing but **you need the callback to the same activity where you start the authentication process**. I think Coinbase API not intended to use that way.

To resolve the issue, simply specify the launch mode `singleInstance` for the activity by adding the following attribute to the activity tag.

```
android:launchMode= "singleInstance"
```

See the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack) for more details.

Comment: The activity I've put the intent filter on **is the exact same activity that calls the authentication process**. On most devices, everything works fine. It is just that **on some devices**, the activity is generated inside the browser, existing basically twice, as the original activity is still active and waiting in the app itself (in background. **The launchMode is singleTop already.**

Comment: Yes both. The weirdest thing is the difference between devices. I have two different Android 7 devices with one behaving as intended while the other doesn't. How much of a role does the browser and its version play in that scenario and what are the reasons behind that behavior anyway?

Comment: I don't know in detail. But I think if  `singleTask` mode is not working too, then it may be launching as a different task in some that particular type of devices only. Just try `singleInstance` if you haven't already.